# Solutions to simple Diophantine Equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all solutions to the equation $3^x - 3^y = 3$ where $x, y$ are positive
integers (or show there are none).

I know there are no solutions to this, so I know I can set up the proof for 2 cases: $x \le y$ and $y\le x$, but not too sure how to go from here.

Comment: Divide the equation by $3$, then you will easily see why this equation has no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have $3^x-3^y=3$, then dividing by $3$ we get:
$$\frac{3^x}{3}-\frac{3^y}{3}=1$$

Which we can simplify to: $$3^{x-1}-3^{y-1}=1$$

To do your proof by cases we can look at $x\ge y$.

If we list powers of three out:

$3^0=1, 3^1=3, 3^2=9 ....$ They all differ by at least 3  never by one so no solutions! You can do the otherwise and argue the same way !